# Lower Bound on VDW Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I am trying to find the original proof given by E. Berlekamp that for prime $p$,

$$W(p+1) \ge p2^p.$$

All the papers that I have searched only reference this result and give no proof.

Comment: The reference is Elwyn R. Berlekamp. [*A Construction for Partitions Which Avoid Long Arithmetic Progressions*](http://cms.math.ca/cmb/v11/cmb1968v11.0409-0414.pdf), Canad. Math. Bull., **11**, (1968), 409-414. [MR0232743
(38 #1066)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=232743).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Thanks! I was interested since Berlekamp apparently gives an algebraic proof.

Comment: It is pretty, and the requisites are low (a basic understanding of finite fields).